# What word/phrase describes the act of "pulling the chair when someone's sitting"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or phrase that succinctly describes the act of pulling the chair when someone's sitting?

If there isn't a word or phrase that describes this act is that (*pulling the chair when someone's sitting*) an appropriate description of the act?

Comment: How about 'bloody stupid'?

Comment: @WS2 Huh? So it would go "He did a bloody stupid with him?".

Comment: I would probably add 'thing'. He did a 'bloody stupid thing' with him.

Comment: @WS2 Question updated. Plus that doesn't sound decent, irrespective of the fact that the act might not be decent (keeping aside close friends).

Comment: Apparently it's practically a national sport in India. [Who is the best Chair puller ? Chiranjeevi or Balayya or Naresh?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqPVk2FJDBc)

Comment: Why would anyone want to pull a chair that someone is sitting in? As a practical joke, I’ve seen people pull away chairs that someone was _just about to sit in_, but pulling a chair that someone is actually sitting in would just be a very slow and floor-damaging way to move a seated person around. Any language that has a specific word for this is spoken by people with too much time on their hands, if you ask me.

Answer (score 6):

Clunky as it seems, there is a preponderance of examples of **"pulled the chair out from under..."** in Google.  It is also idiomatic to mean that someone is caught off-guard or unprepared as in this example:

[Grizzlies pull chair out from under Durant and Thunder, take Game 2, 99-93](http://www.welcometoloudcity.com/2013/5/8/4311288/2013-NBA-Playoffs-Thunder-Grizzlies-Game-2-Final-Score-Kevin-Durant)

Comment: Yep, if the person has not yet completely sat down then "pulling the chair out from under him" is the the set phrase that I've always heard.  Never heard a single word for it, or even a shorter phrase.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it. Do you know any language that would have a word for it? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Decathedration? Used by Alexander Hamilton in 'The History of the Ancient and Venerable Tuesday Club'(1745-1756). Although I admit the accompanying illustration shows on that occasion they're pulling the sitting person out of the chair, rather than the chair from under the sitting person.

http://nationalhumanitiescenter.org/pds/becomingamer/ideas/text4/tuesdayclub.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The best generic description might be "pratfall", which began as an expression that meant "to fall on your buttocks".